# Magento 2 different Exceptions

Tags: magento2, exception

When you look in the core code of Magento 2, in F*ramework/Exception*, you see that there is many different kinds of Exceptions. Most of them are very obvious by their name, but what is the purpose of these ones :

1. LocalizedException ;
2. StateException ;
3. IntegrationException.